# Artifactory service not stopping on Windows

Tags: installation, artifactory

What is the right way to stop the Artifactory service on Windows?

I have installed Artifactory OSS 7.35.1 on Windows Server 2012 R2, as a service.  I copied artifactory-oss-7.35.1 to C:\jfrog and renamed it C:\jfrog\artifactory.  As Administrator, I run

```
C:\jfrog\artifactory\app\bin\installService.bat
```

The service starts and `sc query artifactory` says it's running.

I execute `artifactory.bat stop` and it finishes without errors, but `sc query artifactory` says it's still running.  After issuing `sc stop artifactory` and `sc query artifactory` I get STOP_PENDING.

I get the same behavior after a fresh install if I omit the `artifactory.bat stop` command.
I get the same behavior on Windows 10 using artifactory OSS 7.35.2.

I don't know how to get `sc query artifactory` to tell me the service is stopped.

Comment: With no responses after 9 days and no alternate way to report to JFrog, we resolved the issue by deploying on Ubuntu instead of Windows.

Comment: I have the same problem on Windows Server 2022. I opened https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-27061